# XmmpFramework + Openfire: manage offline messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I've developed a chat-app on iOS using XMMPFramework.

All works great unless network is ok, take this example.

A joins room 'foo'
B joins room 'foo'
--- If I watch server situation, I can see that there is a room named 'foo' with 2 users inside, great! ---

In this situation, A and B can send and read messages sent to room 'foo'.

Now, testing a random lack of network, I put iPhone with user B in airplane-mode and the weird thing is here: Openfire server still have 2 users in room 'foo'.

Why?

By the way, concretely problem is that if I send some messages from user A while B is 'offline' on the phone (but online in server), when I re-establish network, messages sent doesn't arrive.

How can I workaround on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If user A knows that user B is offline then you have to send offline message to user B. If user B could not get offline messages then you have to upload offline message on PHP server using web services, So user B can get offline messages using that web services.